# How to send a message to the specific agent in anylogic?

Tags: anylogic

I am working on a DES-ABS model, where I need to send a text message to itself.

So, the main agent has the following objects

[image]

So there is a source, delay, and sink block. In addition to that there is an agent population called students.

In source block, I am generating only one agent. So the agent number of that agent is 0 by default.

Now, inside the agent type Student, I have the following statechart
[image]

Now I am moving to the operational part,

The transition is set to on message arrival "Swipe"

[image]

On the main agent, you will see once the agent enters the delay block I send a message using

send("Swipe", this)

But once I run the mode, the transition is not firing.

I have also tried using send("swipe", randomFrom(students), this works but this is not something I am aiming for.

Can you please give your valuable feedback?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are sending a msg to `Main`, not the student. The keyword `this` refers to where you are in your model hierarchy.

Use `send("Swipe", agent)` to send it to the passing agent

Learn about model hierarchy here: https://anylogic.help/advanced/code/access.html#where-am-i-and-how-do-i-get-to

Comment: send("Swipe", students1.get(agent.getIndex())); will this work sir?

Comment: Should be the same result, try it out yourself :)

Comment: it works actually